# Flutter MediaQuery the body size

Tags: flutter, media-queries

I am trying to create 3 sections in the body, but I would like that these 3 always cover the entire screen.

```
Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
```

[Result Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grS7B.png)

MediaQuery is taking the entire screen as reference, that is why the last section overflow the same height as the appbar.

Is there any way to use the body as a reference for MediaQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `Column` with children wrapped by `Expanded` , each child will have the same size.

```
  Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.red),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.green),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 4):

actually yes when you get the height of container inside body

```
(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
 appBaa.preferredSize.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) * 0.3,
```

here we give the %30 of body to this container,
you must have a reference of appbar in this case its appBaa and get the height of status bar by padding